# PySpark: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'

Tags: python, psycopg2, emr, amazon-emr

I'm using `Psycopg2` in a PySpark job and I'm providing it in a zip file that contains all dependencies. The build script does this:

```
python -m pip install -t build/dependencies -r src/requirements.txt
```

where `requirements.txt` is

```
SQLAlchemy
psycopg2
```

It then zips `dependencies` and I provide it to `spark-submit` through `--py-files`. When I run the job on EMR, SQLAlchemy is imported just fine, but I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'
```

If I removed `psycopg2` from requirements and installed it on EMR manually (through `pip`), it'd work just fine. Python version on both my machine and EMR is 3.4.7, but my machine is a Mac (whereas EMR is linux).

Answer (score -1):

This is works for me.

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(url='jdbc:postgresql:dbserver', dbtable='schema.tablename').load()
```

sqlalchemy connection not working for me.

```
create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@/dbname")
```

Try your DB connection to sqlcontext, will works.